# why is the dataframe based on value in a column empty?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, series

I have a dataframe and i am trying to extract a subset dataframe based on a value in one of the columns

by using:
`df.loc[df['column_name'] == some_value]`

but instead of a dataframe, I get a dataframe with all the column headings and empty rows.

how do i extract the rows properly?

Comment: Because there are no rows in that DataFrame satisfying your condition. Check if you have mixed up strings and numbers or if you have trailing spaces somewhere.

Comment: Recheck the condition to ensure if there are any values in the dataframe that satisfy the condition. A typical error is comparing a string/object type column using integer or float in which case the condition won't be satisfied. In that case, you may need to change the datatype and then compare.

Comment: checked it, and fixed it. thanks!